# how to create a list of buttons which lead to their description and a radio button to mark them important?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin-studio

I would be glad that someone could help me with the thought of having a list of buttons on which radio buttons are there to each individual button on it.

u could check for the attachment or have an idea what buttons I've thought of to ask you for help.

the red marked buttons(Radio button) seems to me over the top of an another regular(Button)

so can we execute the similar button UI in android?

if possible please let me know. I'm working on Xamarin.android on IDE Visual studio 2017 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLgK1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

A `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation is a good place to start.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:width="match_parent"
    "android:height="wrap_content"
    "orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox ... />
    <TextView ... />

    <!-- Search icon -->
    <ImageView ... />

    <!-- Search icon -->
    <ImageView ... />

    <TextView ... />

    <!-- Delete icon -->
    <ImageView ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i'm grateful about your contribution. can you also please show me the designer view of your code with the source so that I could trace out your layout.  @Minas Mina

Comment: @BhaveshShah I did not actually code this layout, this was just an example (because you'll need to specify the correct margins for each view) to get you started.